# How to calculate each cell in row

Tags: c#

how to calculate each cell in a row and add that data calculaed into the new column called "%bin"

Original datatable:

```
In system | Bin1 | Bin2 | Bin3 | ... | Bin100 |
----------|------|------|------|-----|--------|
3598      | 3590 |  0   |  5   | ... |   3    | 
1500      | 1495 |  3   |  2   | ... |   0    |
```

And  I would like to do below :

```
In system | Bin1 | Bin2 | Bin3 | ... | Bin100 | %Bin1 | %Bin2 | ...
----------|------|------|------|-----|--------|-------|-------|------
3598      | 3590 |  0   |  5   | ... |   3    | 0.99  |   0   | ...
1500      | 1495 |  3   |  2   | ... |   0    | 0.99  | 0.002 | ...
```

Mycode :

```
int i = 0;
int[] sum = new int[101];  
for (i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
  sum[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(BIN" + i.ToString() + ")",string.Empty));
  if(sum[i] == 0 )
  {
     dt.Columns.Remove("BIN"+i.ToString()+"");
  }
  else
  {
     dt.Columns.Add("Total"+i.ToString()+"", typeof(decimal));
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
       decimal rowSum = 0;
       string stringsystem = row["In System"].ToString();
       int system = Convert.ToInt32(stringsystem);
       string stringBinnum = row["BIN" + i.ToString() + ""].ToString();
       int Binnum = Convert.ToInt32(stringBinnum);
       decimal d;
       d = (Binnum / system) * 100;
       rowSum = d;

       row.SetField("%Bin"+i.ToString()+"", rowSum);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what problem you are facing with this code? How to caclulate value of `%Bin1`, `%Bin2` etc... ?

Comment: The result is incorrect and calculate just first column. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You can create a calculated column in datatable with expression. Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vNG1V